# create cron in android app

Tags: android, cron

I have a problem, I need to make a method run every so often, the problem is that all my methods need an Activity to start and do not know how I need to give that activity. Try to create a Service and work with a timer but the problem radico that. I leave my methods for you to see.

```
public void push(Activity activity,String codigoEvento){
    SessionManager manager = new SessionManager();
    folioEvento = manager.getValue(activity,"folioEvento");
    nombreCliente = manager.getValue(activity,"nombreCliente");
    if(!(folioEvento.equals("") || nombreCliente.equals(""))){
        ConnectionInternet cn = new ConnectionInternet();
        if(cn.isNetworkAvailable(activity)){
        String ids = "";
        bdTickets = new TicketsBaseDatos(activity, "Eventrid", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = bdTickets.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT inscripcion_id FROM Inscripcion WHERE validado=1 and sincronizado = 1 and codigo_usuario =SI-1",null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
             do {
                ids += c.getString(0)+",";
                ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
                valores.put("sincronizado","1");
                String[] args = new String[]{c.getString(0), codigoEvento};
                db.update("Inscripcion", valores, "inscripcion_id=? AND codigo_evento=?", args);
             } while(c.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        c.close();
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(Config.URL_BASE+nombreCliente+"/"+Config.URL_PUSH+folioEvento+"/"+ids);
        try {
              String status = json.getString("status");
              if(status.equals("1")){
                  System.out.println("BIEN");
              }
              else{
                  System.out.println("MAL");
              }
          } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: vamos al chat y te echo una mano

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/50170/papap?tab=general

Comment: no puedo creo, podemos chatear por gmail??

Comment: No puedo porque no tengo suficiente reputación para chatear... contactémonos por correo por favor.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no lines in your code that require an `Activity`. There are many lines that require a `Context`. An `Activity` is a `Context`. A `Service` is a `Context`. If you change your `Activity activity` parameter to `Context context`, it would appear that your code should work using a `Service` instead of an `Activity`.

Comment: I made the change you named me, but even so I send error in the following line of code. bdTickets = new TicketsBaseDatos(context, "Eventrid", null, 1);
     SQLiteDatabase db = bdTickets.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: @user3403139: You may have better luck using [an Android developer support site](http://www.andglobe.com) that is in a language that is more comfortable for you. Otherwise, please explain what the "error" is.

Comment: Thank you, really you had every reason, Sorry for the language, this forum is the best unfortunately is in English and not use it much.